# How to decompress PHP script from GZIP?

Tags: php, gzip

I just came across a PHP script that seems to be compressed. I couldn't seem to find any tool online to decompress it. I'm not sure if I'm using the right term. Can someone shed me some light?

The script looks something like this:

```
<?php eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('FZjHDqvIFkV/pWfdLQZgMnojTM5gMpMncs6Zr2/u0BbCVLHr7LX8V37E3T/lUw9FF2/5P0m85jj6/yxPxyz/528+anhuMUe+9YrJL7LAus75ORgk1I1k5r8lcDg6SK6e25aDQa1+0S+mrgIDADqgMgJIOoHrYG1M/oC/qDd/xWAisGqfmgxcnBSUXN/L0ejoop7Nayc2dEFR9GPT81Jcid6OuzhiVH2z+s8fS0Muq0rK84/E81r1NfvdNBlinn+DcrGtK7XNRci5jJbF8SgoVfPYDn+R63mfZa+c58eQ4t0Um0N1G4FyoWv46jeKgpIBcRidPub0iB8guIiQE2A3vU80oUl+KKRc0ALC3YeToiJi8z2tu4K+ZleKAdqh8rBFCAcqa5QbTfAUFHCqP7B8/tWZYln85uhpnJDRIWJb8pOXWCSjH8/JiSyS86qgZpC7dlQwWKxfbLlZ8IrsRF344gl8RV2s9AuGPk2glaBQg1oe9btmcTDyQD35q7lUF8xZK7PoqHCKYySPtegJCvXFqjpa+MoF3lMpB13VXXJH1fIlDn3DIZ24xIh/LPvdPfL64HexDw/GylokZkIktVXC4/I8kSXMSdHzexyvoPH0c9g5YttjkmqKM38rPdsIenVkV/lKGgDkuyOUbusovo/zTBOcAiVhFgmKVknboUhBGhWbOx+5LtrfKXNIQtvYHH8j2swDrG161QaQlrfVxSeyXdsNudtUIIDBP/Xd4QcF0NwQYvW8J5CckrdcxIfFn4sVJIe4UlHz6aocRjJT/7qWuGDCF1FlO15uznMX53NW4mx239Pzqp8WXLgwKF/2ksVfmfsDsAdmsncMM10zYfec6tKedg7o5VAMAoUsAlmci8W+g0NdRnDUXN8O4tJBs1WNDN0mcXh5Rm/Jtq5+3Az610OW/kfkUdmSJBIBnc7eXVaeotV/YMDxuQSY74ESz1Lc9pLd+ji1QP/eV5HDRrdEuQ5jv6FRjwZlfvG4A4PIX5zpnNFCpcwN1D5g8ElFcsmSQSrSqXtGJJ7GDDmBj5dlnScr3/tQW1r86aIvRkPurNz3YFC/xXwGKW1I7XjH5sNHnlRVlKsAH6IU2fYPK50TMtIxliGpJVaCPzgZWLCqFOcDbBglPtyYwWy54pusBjw2zletRwzb0VgTnAydiuph8XUIDk0JV22ytvf9NFAN3BYKcTIt+jjoNXNRA6Cnp+nNolYcZNTe9Rv+qrc5Y69uMuR+WMzWYsvmDxq+EDsXXbJrDAOCLdIMckk8TLxPDORSPRcKENxRtXIwnzvsiRodcCyLb3GgJN/ef/7RVYSpWhVR4xK8rvxX1fRvcPvAOxEUlfsaeiA7Eq5eAKXmsKTXqr06J6nZDjQMp3gpCXChAXNGQOl+PqFtXyNFNl1kDrWbhnFjfctHVSXXa4pOSv2LHfX+6j4tUE8NR/yGS8C/B+gSpKpbH15Bqt0qTPGLUEUSmxPVN/g7Rp1JQ5IjvQZIU5A1+3z4Ef4Z8yrELLP0npvCS8cv3fXON52ERgxPbRZKCxrG9FhPzSIU42/hUvnP/Ym/IridOztl0221kieTrsoSjbeK4Qplx/AHwjlcJOwViLF0TSXOru6/SUehTpgi+1rxuqyaUfdA3QhbY9d8lBTWWGpRTLHtdIhLWOHiVkoqoAqu9xAhFn+j9fN6EN2aRM5B+HYGFk+CmO0juU3HrqMR4PktK4N1cmIer0IDdcpxhyAiFgeh2K3UA5Tsza6umS76Ta+mVzXB2n1/0g6MLHhhxQ3fJQSKnlvcdEVBwHK0q74eBT+3yGbpCFzIQtBjXsSLIjOzs41zBGX58lsu6g3pbqUmn29C3PIMsPqm5eRCifdjyYI3brFd6NcKLMekQQ8m1ckp53XIVVwAeyVi9/juSpOf+IdY62e9t3Cmqjd9PqvbRbF/6YM3y7HFIpAh5SdFRj0f0wyHFveGsWJSxYoW6fdc9bFD8oJRIrts7JafVnyDmSIFDI4vsso04fGaXPUFkvegHC2/kUIOjFx815Gn6vuT4ODN/mCNeuIt0m6d38x+syBfsWJ/TVmd3hR2b7yTXjIrOtoRlLGrKYQDETy6vhFlQwTksmXldwybPc00ppCHHC+Ju+Aa8LMJBP/Vat3McP8MSkKdJvNV6GHkN6U4+5DJDXRqlLiuDjKVFlTgGP1cZuOgK3/fc3dlvxiqbUNzCeGBR48lokybCA2Joufk82Re36ofOeaCvd1mFMnVB9qXCDaBLBS/piL4YpwAjomKxh6yhhbqSWhUVeL2La9NMMKquOe4K1GU8BoICiMuYNrD43pmZ6SYQ7XvSkjhHaYnGrCYPgz5YKaT4pcOp/18y59c07TRgtxHAF/tQ18mI1woRD9tiaM7WtK+nP3zO0t3wZyaFoXFN4qyBL6PIU38QGkvISOJQKhkd3XNQkLOPaCv73DHyCii+6MT5toFLiKppdpOAJvLo9AvTW8zwPvPwW9Zs+u/dYHV2gCk3+6pS90I7nBe+MCldIH4kau92c/uvQ9x+qE/HzmbngmSHaiZ2UfjVCKARB+4Rbg9crB55LJsv6llCq6aLRFVVOZH7a7SUQIk0IO979fm3MJFLGM2ULXHHpBWVKxM8SdqvLZ2nDFhz75v+/L8eysx2Lr+ikJ1hAHGp21gayKqTtURIkFojQ9dYE2xCEI8HxSCtjtO2rW6CNu7SkCmEM8c5+RNXi2OGpwVqjOxREaHBDkJkWPqmWuTa7RCMxL7WZo9/LCDFrN3Cy2rYiTyLb6DC9RbIh9BbC6llCWX6zv88pmQqHgsYA/LunH8/PbYKVO9laR+3vsKD8gBm5X4sVUyRp6KKVLtBDQ/kA7WlNI6EHU/FHaw6d10ZdeCFkbjGeu+1Y9kS8xHcD+oUZRBS0Rzqrblpj0QCKNex+8TknQf3tkJj++6TTSUiXRLxdRl7JH7zcya45uCA+870QZ8AZVrOB1gpV+0dNgpL1mmvXviHFChcLjxIFhWFhA5DSNRU5VWIiRsNbzMFIkxtZYhQW3mMR+zkwz9iVsomXeDK3tUHIZ35tZPfZyTltayVUGC+Eggkc2USwsGuh/Tj1IFdur8wa70xk9XDBjeZA1RVDeygxuRPs98tNT8mSGf1G03FSMT9Jbss3nhQWxuNwCTnBMvnMjsdNbmWz4/gll9ThbaqK2OUbU4h6TorCQLhjTNPxM3MCA61lWReUTEl9fiKQ0v5sMbEBHDo/CKF4OOZtV5DtXZ3NNLZYGvkBoi5x/fBCmz2xmuDYPMGMsVj0wTE6Lf/pKK+qR+r4w+QyPsQ3j9Dli3z3O1BDPi+Lyjx4zYDx4ANtyKICR3sc6ObqC0xUqnlL4X8HyLm2pngWTOMKompBbqaWfwVp+R1f4d+omAy5wFoNNROZN1ce6Dfs+kOrK6LDRZ2i5LBpI61IUYjsHi66eYymm4LiMQDoeCqe4aFh1HwE8xvw1MpJa/NQnqPEJ1aP6JBfsldJjxxXriHCl0hJUsSt8ArcM/BbFA0ooA2bq+ZAsnZWINDwAxYZKCD6uOcw9GimbcfgFuEYW5FD/CK1IXxsnMVsAVqZDxwTIXiRTrZSEipsDSnfiedkpo1qlFwgSNSI3zOFKcNl2WlZJuu/Ndxz7YJ4WORZJyOkUxOr6qEF6iYH0PHEsZ83CeWUuwll1iJuzq9sPDTApawKKcNtd4wUKK2pUBe/94O/KT2IAn2KDxQVnSSZlTjuM7SPjrFKsMDkQx/DL0Q//g/fCX8QuJ6ocKDdLwgJ8Y/+SMOEuIjDEf7/Eh0G4R4uv3uSGEM+NxiFvFWHMXOJp7fUbqnYzvdrzxwSFwr+ek8wkXsKvOQdmQc/zozzKkEIQ4EZf2j+XTxG4zMGQywI5JhSFp4dwOLG+oXwfk7OlqNvxLgEfLXYBPy+kstwYegnxUaNRE0yfqrcv5xYMfHLsBa7PjMFJjOZFG4t9HxlrhPNQm6SXAGrNi4HQ8rt7SAERgZrmoJhQTLfglax+Pa6x2hPw2tSMZUDCo32/Wfw1cqWI7Nsisrl/wUlHiTBJFG2Z+jamUBCPYQ+nz6/M3yMy9EXHYBvsKBcgDUkaR97SZkOa01F/zlH4jcgoBYTF39AwLs1r1iglsn/5YlIWgeBrRrlv1V9ny8FcQLu8rmAmvKKtg18rUshOX+yI86KRjfHGdx8Y4MZBUXhucnLuLDvqnAICwHETo4QVMnVXWWWcOiWoEyxvZgKzXrnRuTJsiiEeaZkkY4cnOHVrYN3oeGayvD2zM0t05LWe+GQ/jNXj9e9vUpnqznCjIiBqN/AkgIH+pNa9mvKB4t42BeLUB1iyiECcAPCFtI5sdWqVat6aRwnKswJzMYUnwzirbtbfJAHj6dMIRwmehwJ01HOscrJH1bz5JBqgIXTxxQG+wyYFySRpWrgpAixloC2Ksd5fK4qP8VB5XbDqJaAwuCmXtV2Xc7QZqhps0zyk1aWsvVQuRKnuqAgr4cZJ1DO13RsHpTfcv9iQD+tbxxAo1cs5bvVQlbYD7ke6CyNvmTy6E9aTooNhGGGetforY1o3ZGFnUnINzW+EoXcGNuGLz1G5yAmN+XZfdXXjGvy1ddC++OXFGW3nytqkT5Mu3BCWKZpzOIamd8nyT9+Ht2Lhj0SF0oqMjCpe9lLV7YU9dkBfEP+cPuhnVyubmOhJwFyyZJdHrSfsOVQSaRM6jwkS4WmdQjmj6XkyelyTi/shFT2MlKRtzFNZLz3zDGAXsdPzdJBLq2gkOzFakcIT0ebfTCaoeuMWzY0VcmaUa4E+7KwxAlPHXEqmlFrZGGhID/FafpFEE1i5ZSNeEEyLXO3wsKiW2oOdOzatF1Ut5ZjFokpG9KdrAmnI9TCttopNOP/oKLSE46JLXe3gGNVcghdwgNQQD3o6R50oaI2/SWriEYmVQgaRUuuZQqpSn3G75djPqiEHEyVt0rlL3MrdZFjEQJQFhQ2h9YnrR9U0T2XGExr/rR303I84b0OAd/0PdJff7gOHWQ1+rVW0UjH0pS9Mv/9X82GTgljkrtCVcJX8U5oYq0mnMNijGPNDC/L4Kio6d/pJcGTvmL/P2qEtq3IC7koKdzdFMyGsX8SKwRP/02PJuwOB31ANIc5BDh7V0hqZ4OY6kBFGf7HzoXzUVXuhuX0eWaxDrTgnnUB4OTP+bpO3ZMpXqvXiXsu3WH1egpDpj0HKDBf0RNWhdgOgek1UmGAG6jt5kN3GHiBus9MhQT5X+M7faSBQuyu4Q+MO1iNVT8EsYiZSZv7HqOjWdpsPCxl4yEkiVaqOJ6MtfYuZa3ahcBB60THCeZ7eyYXY/nYh3LVP0PHY9IgsTkDcBbMKhoOLs+3CVS9aa2hx2m03BAsqiC+fe2gBoe5aU65lMlpqaRtW97ZLqDk3QcKy+8W2JbDxji86G0yzsx/5oa8QU9fB88yaA6KOUlJuCDm9vXOAz1sRekb0bZNcFigoiaHF8bfOqHWOX+iNvarEFIT5r7s8BGx4NNCVLGDJyq72VsepD4cTEoTXMOdaDjKF32R7TJ7aw7uRvPhTXE4Y+2rvm9PDzp/0qUX+lpgTaDxUnsj3bLWNrsOiYcHtPpOSlkRu68SyxIm22g/Foj64pybVfzos1rTqRw5on2J5++KFly+sWcKgDgu8ryOfn88sQDoM8EAIaC4HXyZKni8tOlw8ijvDVGFE+P4+/nhL6ZKsmaEFBq4Psnkw29e+Ree1cFB7cGFYSoo1EgrQb+IYDMyn11JsPPHg2TykmoMhdNtC3GuwXrT5fosyCEiO8bOs/Sg4M862vMO2z+LPAdF8GLuDPsjzeej6fr7vIqYM/wWfqLaGJQSEIifsEFtdlKDPrqihN4plg6x/YbwTXRGHvrTVYpdJpGFHoFms5dVaxA237GXL7J2i+T4znHJLTYyRlpsNJ3aiwyPuTBXRwCJdeIjMqkq1YqltiXjtB26ftcCWFY/jeMGbS9uuVXU3wondsujhpIjgcBdviH9STer+mJPTZxFMIA9rcSPtBhfe+rlNdWqgoTA7SudgZsc95K8YZThoWz8VgEZnTRLOd4QpAwgTsZZTnskdymVBjkZHcpekQgcHeBkvGsmF3Pdtc3Z4wyXf7vDgGtZxOaMQU/RhD56KKIp0NoyDE2ab7zFHQjkc2nEx0U5xPj6QbkGZ4dN3pqrG4eTcJynoYsFrRibii1lCW8dE/jmZ8YMVZaBzDe/Zc+hjmpjZ9if1D8D2voib79k0NSZ34rEtCUEnZhg2aTEIzMnjOL47UADBvZhF2Q7WZVp+2RMzcFlOWdn625A/3t4Z49XXlQ3pPSAHECFHfrWzkQzcUbm93cYe1bkFHspgXoW+hQbqSKcEQRo/5wVjVQClY3OVTykvSUX5k4/0k0ubh4rQq/Om7hp19lfkxrdFDVPEkKWR/z6WU8RS73hPD9USAOTXgRzBGstc5qga9pyWqahYDuSDc0lHlL2kC60zHu+49/vwIP8pI/TlA8qUnLtZ6QxSRnSXqldSGssHiTOQkOGQGizh9+KIbXaUe8A4WHiJSsI6wvLg9RHGNyZnlvTie4/Yqd5OtT/pS5kVV7qURPcETbqMa03IqHYLoLkxqMKqX16phtWKlXyA2WthEx5u45lgp4JMooVMBOBdQIOjzXAJq0HOPfsLZkjrgKXFqM2Mo7DHGRyuij/OAqVksSo6fCoDISHvp9YWNSlkOE9MHXA9irurErRhNlS+t/jY7n3EUQ+A5cC0vfDIb5MvBx6s9GgeDkOpkD2PXuT/SvmEKIImkZOsQjMDazJhjJJbMaH+cLK5fFMcT/OfLpJY7dq1Sbds+9XZqVgRhzF9uejC5LUMcfZ1usYOngDxXgTT4EGdoqy6ESNowy6qTmKYtalOAVLNZdfPJM8CgVY+50a2ggdpOMEujoQLzJdQrQMxzPjB9EYno9yDZUUvfViSCDwDUwnPzzoCru5jUBv1Q9m07CWdvtP4WP4kzHTGx2kRgmeo4y8W4LcXT9KepGHDrwplzwycabUrHfALQ8vmiVzZrhuFYnolhaMNiHeBDo6SNJPQjPegh9vVxxAtCx3vycom4CMTn/HZyhGrheZ6qF+xcFD6eKl43EhR5RmG0FPOirsoWByaYX6jOy91uH3mOI4EpXv+uWfIebteJ9aMrpcalyhUIoNqwMHSAFqPwsrH4n7Z+bBGfGmkgK2GQLRCMnwOUrzxugpj6aDsU3kYkYWWfn7cqoxOP+lkwFlcJE9KZlSv3LK8hQC3locRWbCZ79ZY+FpRXUW9go82dfY3gflI65gXOX7P17TNzlYEU4WwgnCbntNxdRi6Fnn85MXm493l42t6WEJAlyx/mhfqRnsCyU5JsxVlPZS4ZlJWu4dzTg3migZsfuaMOVQlZo+HPizrXc1n4bvJtbvtCRQwahFtcC+SbH/RW23zZX949SkYs5OD3FtIoByPlVUynSlXsauzhxS+vWPGX28wMMKEKWZyqz1qjhEzrVWP1ByTlYZxfAGhWgGPy84zp7YeZUA9IIVK/Q1B4y/qDkAL70OxoWj5nFi1YdLokuqh/PR/DTIRJtiwTge5HHIv3nZFY9W6ul+1ftVNwPwDbRyRY7Eexz/GKbD3eM7yTiaJAVRzbn0rYusFj8W9zmYLFp6TgZeeSUH38jv9JPcLZtLWPYqA7o2H828hmJ3Ao0JGtR9NZ9EWk333bZrB/vremJoxxeQJdpueMfGPLPz+CYlSWSaafZjwW+GhW+DetX1j8/fYnMdeIJ8b3RMTunJxgy3y0eH0ejjCtj62GNRi6wU9Zf/PkZqz9Ad/vyrUtC6i1URK5t54PCcoM0YgirgHNErOZs/qHN4NZ3R8LXYtGefTMqx/a5RGgQwfWg+IfNxu2s7fjac6vKIGAHVR9WCg3bQWoN6qdC5IxB3mplUba89QurHavYR4lYsHVovt1BUXz96R4LjrLH/eQFdB2mvPdznxzkBCp1IUe3CG+mhBxZuAVhI6hKefRKexgKQfwlbxZoVgMvQI0XwZvQQEiG1mCc50twoKuLYEthSfb9npa3B/7vMGXlVjAZFCrOdJUHxDkyKGTttoV5xnrm18GjrIUAtqp0Kj7vVyVY2dq0KewtHfWMcUV5aeQNcenRFttO8wPX0LL14d8dVX9vLs2wKUay4PbIU574Dz5cTLgJmWtOsHazPvCWzwWHKbvrjeHIhjJQFs7wodz4Q+5E3bU3zUkq7h8bVsA4LNT5D/uJu5nqjWV/UrQdYLQdxniiJbQCUe59J6dGe7B2moNwEhXMDtJ4uahUHQ6AhGGD42QG8PrxvfVXqGpMRlnTPjimnYOBsrRH5PdJW67rJN3BHpG+cL/Qg5jvLEk2W85n82yS4jC+TJYPdCbaqdHxCqgN9j95SVgUmVPYo0Vnjao/toOVNuvxrKDOtKft3SOxdVPY7daXkTRr1arOL5qBUArEXpquhY15qN5k7eMygS3RcbxoNLgMwxdGTS/1ucY8gdaciTf7Irf5/FQnyrBzJuS4hSBAvMkzNmJYuldlBYPP6vBmyJ9CerQI3dT91ns8uySM6+b5/iwT4Mdae4thLyUXmOy75UcD0jaQWelCfRHgTR2ty3mYHdIfX0bh/ZX1FaNCHXn6Fw8RXPYNgvx89wB2S/60qsn3E8wcKvgJIcGxicEvGSQ6Rx+I+nNQiS5mjZlaF53nqJVzPGCEAEfxweBCEWAoADMP5MnCfOv7p0okpbthAjJ/nTZKpUh1jlbXbLiXBk0OVnNcc+WsQKP7PPeUP7AmS9x4UMS2fSUBYBuuwHKTf379U2qtuD1uUj5acAsM2WLGWxPSU2b9EKEnyP4teUn9n6FNvIN1FgFtz0WQojbs23fp9Aa0MSOnVF/d/T2VSwhG/hLO2kBXNqHzfK2Q+OtzbWfJWKrmOqIaax7r0FrLUDNFOn2O+TxZzIBQSW4bvXqr1PPIqQuYLG9XSJoFVbHtXq4hwztdmgPy3cvRQRTqkjF7CfpawykbddaeeyHerVkACE3QSnLKPkVYY7MeNAnpGInfL7O1tCWCeBMyem/blRpyw4mvA0wew/SDRnPDuXEj+uxaDmi2dskptYlpQ6WKULsze/kDYnlE8ZnvFH/wKQfuuppwSTOXhjU+6l+/OJgmnUEeXMFaSUFP5ACPtitrUY3flqQzQGL1m1hecTg7ioJewmk3rji1y2qWQPkGYZ1tzXoE8aTagiq53yXYveSUthwqz9/N26dcG4itpMhoQLV1+zX/K6VzJZUQ/WbWPHNS8pDgq0YvMHj59ZGOMUVMepTIexh0cyjE0ZSQYiISFAHI32+3a+yeKPVv49rZ/KnKSr0bffGmCV7hH/uwwxCMV7wYo8r3GzfCuAeBdAJ+P1N6eBw0rU8xlaWzWmTAMapHb1V8U0lIyDFIUH9bb/TsSmsFnxwhHqsW2NbCDvZFtA/7i4xEEvRL8sq+fHnn4JeJM6n5T0gCdiJYPcNGvIljOkKg6gfAn+GtQGqYxUnhlTlDzhM28sgnx6dMXQNm+wJuO2W3s/P0dxQyeK9FWN9ddqDAC8lHRr8dLK9xHzWkEcrwRyv5HTKt1aiEwPu0phEPvt9l3cPSA6QJFP/kKupQ2oYtRN0vo+YPwgN93n9sZO9Nm8tnMKuhhPArZGYSbGFL/qwPWA3+lyU39q2DBrpuVDFDwdMTu5ZkOwBMflm97tguuxtpujzR8P7O3V91Fhpn8QAEy6WKKUJubH7b6airWsrIH0G37fvsBG1hcouyrjHIaKEi7E1wvIcSgPmzM3+UYrNxjJ4YFDu0qCcPjTyRTv0pUFzQBFekUBOkEmgeYn/+wxRZ5eMNmzUBvM27bDAfEG/jcV/GM2wX5V6wTMGtp+lvAAfWcGhrHF9Gs8Vk/lKa1F3KO/xUtRkX93DBTDbXH7zvr89P3gP+cFTl1Z7KE/SZ4Q9j+C/FWRcDs8Z0UpJr2gkYYt+ibiB8ug5qeTUS4PrUqH/vWoq6YGZe0NFrLaZxTq3uZ8NlhtZZSVtTUU9bfJ1+05s7hx2MQP8/NKwAce6BM63w+vK9Ct6ySBCu7gks5IX4IDtxNgJGhFyTM3zL1ik4idysr3vOX8H0AIiCx7TcUl1lEMq4HC+0d8Ss0c9GLCnayyZlWrrastMzURKStIrVJe2SygmFkcnGE4eCubluQsiU5bPlAqd6iFLPk/oiLyBhV4SZ5yctIGc9RHjhlXUwQ8AMoC8FgFW51rVBUq4PKghpp2XkigX3qAMSYwCkK4iWIrsoIk5wKDXlgwbTQZKD3r+rtAkwbHu/FcSW72PvoEvUt8ZAZ+3VDICSx1Q74XMW9gHBqKCTAWpkkEnasKIMsXnO1FXHkxi5Ya2p2Z0krjgbHQcfRC/ejYkYHylRw0h380EmZuu+Kamu+ILlQM7EjzyIIjKAnxDXCJwMZseDgPAOQ7vZg5p9LkLoKlGYmWvcsygHqtLWM7ltM+w6ogOBB/ZRwuHYptT4hFhjEmZLQU07kv6xSBAjBJ8A+7myP1q6qnj7DW3sEg2nqN6gfgZvRLpU20mid7ddF4sn/5oys3RSgPytVu9wDVUZOYj2XHvuT6y0f1AMeSlq4eNrxKObDn1cXXYHuIcsYE79Td2+XyQl4jP1OixddKszBa5WqBxbRDd3xroF3F5zeTjsCEi5kgoASdjhoK1S/CVg7xGXyrO9gbLHTCyC8fGsYWFZ8a0g88F/uJ5tIwO8++r+D2Aw9eOFHTCvvl6JsybMLKxlrQFPOzWJVtjlIsu/FM8tRutgu/QFyeGG0fQTktgEWStz9Z/QnSXrgW5P+RISccdY9nAncOvLuupZQwn8L/UDwNEmVUSYjjR4UDbC4a+GGKXIKYQHg5YGYY9zTtZZjUuhoSi9MBvRF4tdAdgAMya/RnsC5iT79TYOafr9D1OWaMLGqC8wi/TchOCGQDqoEjpFDGJvrAUaVWYWAZk2U5toG/9dM/IiUKPJVqexnyZagp+vC/Bz9F5HC9scVTThvX3xeIbUU8SgC3uNxsiVf8JHhPAormpdJO815GmE0plbjwl7askAoIAAIAgeIzm3//+++///voP'))); ?>
```

Comment: try this: http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php

Comment: Just replace `eval` with `echo` and so on again, if needed. It is for one time job, but also very easy to write a script that will do it for you.

Comment: http://www.unphp.net/decode/f28ead9af92f91055ab8406851e9cadb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can decode it using below urls:

1) http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php
2) http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/
3) http://toolki.com/en/php-decoder/
4) http://www.unphp.net/

Comment: Hi Suresh. Why this one can't seem to be decoded? -- http://www.unphp.net/decode/36436141ecea1668212f8974ef8235c5/

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a way to "un-minify" i think - especially when all of the variables and functions are reduced to numbers.